# Team City: Skip web.config when deploying using Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, teamcity, webdeploy

I deploy a project by using build parameters such as:

systemDeployOnBuild = true

system.DeployIISAppPath = [something]

system.DeployTarget = MSDeployPublish

and a few other parameters to target my IIS Web Deploy server.

How can I prevent the web config from being deployed with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to skip it?

Comment: The web config in the deployment folder contains the correct connection strings and environment settings.

Comment: You might check out [web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx).  These allow web deploy to modify the web.config for a given environment as it's deploying the site.  It's a *good thing* and frees you from one of the more error-prone manual deployment steps.  Scott Hanselman talks about it in [this video](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx).

Comment: When there are dozens of destination environments, maintaining the `web.config` transforms for every single machine gets _tedious_. Furthermore, when you distribute to your clients who self-host via a web deploy package that they must execute, you may not even HAVE the values needed for the transform. Better to exclude the `web.config` completely and let the client edit it himself!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define property `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment`. The value is semicolon separated list of files and wildcards to exclude from deployment.

So for exclusion of web config define `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment=Web.config`

Comment: Does this excludes only the web.config in the root or inside individual Areas (ASP.NET MVC, razor) folders as well?

Comment: This excludes just the root file. You should add wildcard like `**\Web.config` to match web.configs in subfolders.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using msdeploy via command line you can use [-skip parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) as follows:

```
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="^.*web\.config$"
```

In this example I'm using regular expression to exclude all web.configs, but you can also type in relative path to your web.config file.